# Which RL algorithm can I apply in practice for discrete state space and (possibly) continuous action space?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to come up with a reinforcement learning pipeline to design the following:

- The agent has a sensor, and the value that could be read from the sensor is a real number. I plan to **map this sensor value ***r1*** to a finite and discrete state space.** For instance I would map the value *r1* to state 0 if the value of *r1* < 0, and to state 1 otherwise.
- Also, the agent can take a particular action with two motors. Each motor takes in an integer value (0 ~ 4095), and rotates according to that value. There will be exactly 4096 * 4096 = 16777216 actions possible, so the action space is discrete.

My first approach to implement this was **Deep-Q-Learning.** I think the action space is discrete in this case, but I can't figure out how to handle those 16777216 actions in the neural net. **So, I decided to view the action space as continuous.** The Actor-Critic method or **Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient (DDPG) method** seemed appropriate for this task, since it could cope with the continuous action space.

But in my case, the state space is mapped discretely to simplify the matter. I couldn't find anything appropriate for this purpose. (**where state space is discrete, and the action space is continuous.**) Or could anyone recommend me of other ways to design the state/action space?